# How to search for all the hidden files in my computer?

Tags: linux, grep

I want to find all the hidden files inside a directory in linux terminal.

I have found out that we have a grep command to search for the file but I need to search for hidden files.

`grep -r search *`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Linux or macOS? You have both tags, but they're different OSes.

Comment: @subodhkalika Do you want to list the hidden files or do you want to run `grep` on their contents?

Answer (score 2):

try this on your terminal too show all the hidden files on your system:

```
find / -name ".*" 2> /dev/null
```

or you can use other way like in this web https://devconnected.com/how-to-show-hidden-files-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

If by "hidden file" you mean Linux file names that begin with `.` that are often hidden by default, (and directories starting with `.` whose contents might also be considered "hidden") then try this command:

```bash
find . -print | grep '/\.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use (with GNU grep)

```
grep -r search .
```

if you want to search *contents* of files in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively.
Note: It isn't clear if you want to search filenames or contents of files.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution:

```
find /dir -name '.*' -type f
```